# C# new array. Class with constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, class, constructor, instance

I am working in Unity but I guess the same applies to C# in general.

this is a class I made:

```
    public class KeyboardInput
    {
        private string name;
        private KeyCode btn;

        public KeyboardInput(string buttonName, KeyCode button)
        {
            name = buttonName;
            btn = button;
        }
    }
```

When I create an instance of the class, if I don't specify the values required by the constructor, I will get an error.

Now I want to create an array of the class and I want to specify the values, but how ?

This seems to be working fine without specifying the values

```
    public class InputController
    {
        private KeyboardInput[] defaultKeyBinding = new KeyboardInput[4];

        public InputController()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < defaultKeyBinding.Length; i++)
            {
                //Something inside here
            }
        }
    }
```

I can tweak the code to be able to set the values inside the for loop, but I am very curious to know if there is a way!

Comment: You mean `defaultKeyBinding[i] = new KeyboardInput(string, KeyCode)`?

Comment: You should create a new instance  of every KeyboardInput array item.

Comment: I'm confused - do you want to create instances when initializing the array or in the constructor?  Where do the values needed by the constructor come from?  What kind of error are you getting now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
private KeyboardInput[] defaultKeyBinding = new KeyboardInput[4];
```

is just declaring an array, nothing is getting initialized yet. In your loop you probably want something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < defaultKeyBinding.Length; i++)
{
    //should look something like this
    defaultKeyBinding[i] = new KeyboardInput("Ayy", KeyCode.A);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will allow you to put your objects in the array without using the for-loop:

```
KeyboardInput[] defaultKeyBinding = new KeyboardInput[4];
defaultKeyBinding[0] = new KeyboardInput("someName", KeyCode.A);
defaultKeyBinding[1] = new KeyboardInput("someName2", KeyCode.B);
```

However, to avoid getting the error that happens when you don't specify values for the paramters in the constructor, you can use optional values. See the example on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). In your case I don't know if it makes sense to assign default values to these parameters, but it would look something like this:

```
public KeyboardInput(string buttonName = "defaultButtonName", KeyCode button = KeyCode.A)
{
  name = buttonName;
  btn = button;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not looking to go around the for loop. but your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
  KeyboardInput[] array = new KeyboardInput[]
  {
    new KeyboardInput("a",b),
    new KeyboardInput("a", b),
    new KeyboardInput("a", b)
  }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as it relates to the question. Don't just post code.